# unknown action with will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my users controller I have this in a method:

```
 @users = User.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10,
```

The results are rendered on users/search.  The 2nd page link points to users/search?page=2, but it leads to an unknown action error.

Comment: show here routes for users_conroller in config/routes.rb

Answer (score 0):

Possibly there is something wrong in routes.rb, so you haven't got `:search=>:get` rout

Comment: map.resources :users,
        :collection => {:search => :get}

Comment: It looks like it is trying to find the show action.

Processing UsersController#show (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-03-28 13:52:45) [GET]
  Parameters: {"action"=>"show", "id"=>"search", "page"=>"2", "controller"=>"users"}

ActionController::UnknownAction (No action responded to show. Actions: check_username, create, disable, edit, enable, hide, index, make_admin, make_mod, new, redirect_to_https, remove_admin, remove_mod, search, see, and update):
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/validates_captcha-0.9.6/rails/init.rb:21:in `call'

Rendering rescues/layout (not_found)

Comment: The users index is a search form.  The results page is users/search and this also is will_paginate page #1 .

Comment: wich rails version do you use?
this looks like error in your routing. try to update your system gems

Comment: I can only recommend you to update your gems (gem update --system)